# Adding a class to all the images excluding a <div> using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I want to add a class to all the images excluding a particular `<div>` using javascript. 
I have made this code that adds a class to all the images in the webpage:

```
$(function(){
    $('img').addClass('posts');
});
```

How is it possible?

Comment: whats your question?

Comment: need html code example !

Answer (score 1):

Use the `:not` selector:

```
$('img:not(#mydiv img)').addClass('posts');
```

Obviously you would need to change the `#mydiv` selector to suit your code.

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/2bnxw94e/)

Answer (score 1):

```
Try

to .addClass()

$('div').not(this).addClass('editable');
to .removeClass()
$('div.editable').not(this).removeClass('editable');
```

Some Code which might help you

```js
$("li").not(document.getElementById("notli"))
  .css("background-color", "red");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<ul>
  <li>list item 1</li>
  <li>list item 2</li>
  <li id="notli">list item 3</li>
  <li>list item 4</li>
  <li>list item 5</li>
</ul>
```

Look at this also

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>not demo</title>
  <style>
    div {
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
      margin: 10px;
      float: left;
      background: yellow;
      border: 2px solid white;
    }
    .green {
      background: #8f8;
    }
    .gray {
      background: #ccc;
    }
    #blueone {
      background: #99f;
    }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div></div>
  <div id="blueone"></div>
  <div></div>
  <div class="green"></div>
  <div class="green"></div>
  <div class="gray"></div>
  <div></div>

  <script>
    $("div").not(".green, #blueone")
      .css("border-color", "red");
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

References
   [.Not](http://api.jquery.com/not/)